# How to get a text file to split by a string in different RichTextBoxes?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, streamreader

My Textfile looks like this:

```
(-*-)
textA1
textA2
textA3
(-*-)
textB1
textB2
textB3
(-*-)
textC1
...
```

Now i try to get the Textfile split up by the `(-*-)` string (<-it´s always this in the Textfile!) and show it in different richtextboxes.
I use actually following Code...

Tried with datatable, stringbuilder, iList...

My Goal is to get all textA in richtextbox A, textB in richtextbox B and so on...

```
 private void öffnenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var seiten = new List<string>();

        if (oFDOpenDatei.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {                
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(oFDOpenDatei.FileName))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string[] read = sr.ReadLine().Split(new string[] { "(-*-)" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    for (int i = 0; i < read.Length; i++)
                    {
                        seiten.Add(Convert.ToString(read));
                    }

                    //foreach (var item in read)
                    //{
                    //    seiten.Add(Convert.ToString(item));
                    //}
                }
                sr.Close();
            }

            rTBA.Text = seiten[0][0].ToString();
            rTBB.Text = seiten[1][0].ToString();
        }
    }
```

-the activ "for" statment shows a "S" in both richtboxes ... for whatever reason :))

-the foreach says out of index, but when i check the array.lenght, it shows me 1 at A and 2 at B ... not more

can someone please get me on the right track!?

Comment: change `seiten.Add(Convert.ToString(read));` to `seiten.Add(read[i]);`

Comment: Does the file always start with `(-*-)` or can there be some text before the first occurrence ?

Comment: `sr.ReadLine()` only reads one line; you want to compare on, not split, that one line. Break that big read statement into separate statements and look at what you are reading in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you want your list to contain array-of-string elements, not string elements. In this case, it should be of type `List<string[]>`.

Second, when you use `ReadLine()`, it returns only **one line**. If you wish to split based on a specific line, you need to read multiple lines.

Here's an easy solution with LINQ:

```
var seiten = new List<string[]>();
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(oFDOpenDatei.FileName);

int consumedLines = 0;
while (consumedLines < allLines.Length)
{
    var group = allLines.Skip(consumedLines).TakeWhile(s => s != "(-*-)").ToArray();
    if (group.Any()) seiten.Add(group);
    consumedLines += group.Length + 1;
}
```

If you don't need access to individual lines of the same group, then you can still use a `List<string>` and adjust the above code to something like this:

```
var seiten = new List<string>();
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(oFDOpenDatei.FileName);

int consumedLines = 0;
while (consumedLines < allLines.Length)
{
    var group = allLines.Skip(consumedLines).TakeWhile(s => s != "(-*-)").ToArray();
    if (group.Any()) seiten.Add(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, group));
    consumedLines += group.Length + 1;
}

rTBA.Text = seiten[0];
rTBB.Text = seiten[1];
```

---

### References:

- [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines).
- [`Enumerable.Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip).
- [`Enumerable.TakeWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile).
- [`Enumerable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any).

Comment: I´m a Beginner ... Maybe you also can recommend some documents to understand this !? :)

Comment: @Thomas Sure thing! Added some references to the answer. Also, here's a quick tip; while in Visual Studio, you can go to the documentation of any member (method, property, etc.) in the framework by highlighting it and then clicking the `F1` key in your keyboard. Good luck! :)

Comment: Is there a way to use the var group id for the boxes ... something like : for(int i=0, i < group.lenght, i++) { rTBA.Text = seiten[i], rTBB.Text = seiten[i] ...} or maybe a foreach ... tried some, but don´t see through it

Comment: @Thomas You can create an array of TextBoxes: `var textBoxes = new[] {rTBA, rTBB,...};` and then use it like this `for (int i=0, i<seiten.Count; i++) textBoxes[i].Text = seiten[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

using Regex

```
    string[] result = Regex.Split(input, @"(\(-\*-\))",
                               RegexOptions.IgnoreCase,
                               TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method. All lines are read from the source text file, then assigned to each member of a `List<TextBoxBase>` (you can include both RichTextBox and TextBox controls), using a selector which is incremented each time a string pattern is found.

If the number of controls in the list is less than number of groups in the text file, the loop will fill only the controls listed then break out.

```
int groupID = -1;
string pattern = "(-*-)";
List<TextBoxBase> controls = new List<TextBoxBase>() { rTBA, rTBB, rTBC };

string[] input = File.ReadAllLines("[File Path]");
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {
    if (input[i].Contains(pattern)) { 
        groupID += 1; 
        continue; 
    }
    if (groupID == controls.Count) break;
    controls[groupID].AppendText(input[i] + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jimmi ... thank´s for your option but it don´t work this way !? Anyway it´s an important information for me to collect txtboxes in a List<> ... truly will help me on different projects. :)